Bulk Api 2 in Apex to delete records
Looking to implement a scheduled job which deletes large number of records (hundreds of thousands, or few millions) from a single custom object.
What's the best way to do this in a an automated and scheduled manner?
I have an existing schedule batchable apex class use BULK API 1, it takes some time to delete the records and I want to use BULK API 2 to make it faster.
Here is my existing batchable api that deletes the records: it takes around 30 minutes to complete the job.
global with sharing class EmpCleanupSchBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable, Database.Stateful {

    private String empRecordType;
    private String query = 'SELECT Id FROM emp_inactive__c';

    global EmpCleanupSchBatch() {}

    global EmpCleanupSchBatch(String empRecordType) {
        this.empRecordType = empRecordType;
        if (String.isNotEmpty(empRecordType)) {
            this.query += ' WHERE Emp_File_Record_Type__c = :empRecordType';
        }
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope) {
        delete scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Post-processing logic, if any
    }

    // Schedulable method to start the batch.
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {  
        Database.executeBatch(new EmpCleanupSchBatch(empRecordType), 10000);
    }
} 


The code you shared doens't use Bulk Api v1 but rather just plain batch class. What am I missing?
Also why do you believe Bulk Api V2 is going to be faster than v2? In my experience either of bulk apis are fast enough but bottleneck is typically automatinos that fire when you delete a record, which is the lowest common denominator for v1 and v2.
